# Fixed points of elliptic isometries in Gromov boundary

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Suppose $X$ is a proper, geodesic, $ \delta $-hyperbolic, metric space. Let $\partial X $ denote the Gromov boundary of $X$.

It is known that isometries of $X$ are exactly one of three kinds:

1. Elliptic (or orbit of $ x \in X $ is bounded.
2. Parabolic (has exactly one fixed point in the boundary)
3. Loxodromic (has exactly two fixed points in the boundary)

**My Questions:**

Can an elliptic isometry fix a point in the boundary?

Can the stabilizer of a parabolic fixed point contain an elliptic element?

Can the stabilizer of a loxodromic fixed point have an elliptic element?

Comment: Your classification is incorrect: Elliptic isometries also can have some fixed points on the boundary. (One, or two or more.)

Comment: I am reading Proposition 4.1 of Kapovich (https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~kapovich/PAPERS/bry1.pdf). May be I am understanding it incorrectly. But it seems like two fixed points = loxodromic, one fixed point = parabolic, otherwise elliptic.

Comment: I think my mistake is to assume that classification is happening by counting the fixed points of g. May be the classification is happening by looking at what <g> is doing. Is that right?

Comment: Here is a classification that I think is true: elliptic: orbit of x in X is bounded, may have some fixed points in boundary.  parabolic: orbit of x in X is unbounded and has exactly one fixed point in boundary; loxodromic: orbit of x in X is unbounded and has exactly two fixed points in boundary. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, your last classification is correct.

Comment: You should say "Gromov-hyperbolic" rather than "$\delta$-hyperbolic" when $\delta$ doesn't need to be specified. To 1: yes, the identity map is an example. On the hyperbolic plane, a reflection is a non-identity isometry with fixed point on the boundary. This also answer questions 2,3 (assuming that "parabolic/loxodromic fixed point mean point fixed by some parabolic/loxodromic isometry).